# pow used to calculate lengths of triangles

Tags: c, netbeans

I´m programming in c and I'm using Netbeans IDE.

I'm trying to calculate the length of the sides of two triangles from their vertexes.  However, when I try to use pow to calculate a square root, I get an error. I´ve included  and when I use for example pow(2,2), it works. It's just this specific example that doesn't work. I've checked the parentheses like five times and they seem correct to me.

[my code looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7x8F.png)

(Don't mind the other variables, so far I'm just working with a1, a2, b1, b2 and c.)

Comment: please code in the question, not as external link/image

Answer (score 1):

You are using (1/2) as exponent in your call to the function `pow`. This is integer division and the result of 1/2 is 0. So this will not give you the square root.

Use 0.5 instead as exponent in the call to `pow`.

Answer (score 1):

(1/2) will give you an integer value. and you need double. 
you can use one of the following ways to avoid this situation.

```
(1.0/2)        // (double/int) = double  
               // or (1/2.0)  

((double)1/2)  // 0.50000 
               // or ((double)1/(double)2)
```

Useful links :

[C - Type Casting](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm)

[Type Casting - C Programming](https://developerinsider.co/type-casting-c-programming/)